# Problemas de incompatibilidade com Plugin BLE com projeto Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin-forms

Instalei um plugin em minha aplicação Xamarin Forms e estou tendo problemas de incompatibilidade:

> Plugin BLE 1.3.0 was restored using .NETFramework v4.6.1 instead of
>   the project target framework .NetStandard Version. This package may
>   not be fully compatible with your project

Como a mensagem diz meu projeto foi criado com a opção .Net Standard e o plugin é compatível para PCL

Ai vem a pergunta como fazer funcionar este plugin sendo que o Visual Studio não dá a opção para criar projetos PCL e somente .NET Standard

Como fazer para que este plugin se torne compatível com meu projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta mensagem geralmente é apresentada como um alerta de compatibilidade, não um erro. Isso significa que o pacote em questão foi desenvolvido tendo como alvo aquele tipo de projeto e se alguma funcionalidade for dependente de algo exclusivo daquela plataforma, ela pode não funcionar.

De acordo com a [documentação da Microsoft sobre o assunto](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/net-standard):

> O .NET Standard é o substituto das PCLs (Bibliotecas de classe portáteis) [oferencendo uma forma mais simplificada e leve de compartilhamento de código independente de plataforma (diferente do PCL que é orientada por perfis que representam interseções de plataformas). Além disso esse novo padrão] é compatível com um subconjunto de perfis de PCL. O .NET Standard 1.0, 1.1 e 1.2 se sobrepõem, cada um, com um conjunto de perfis de PCL.

Uma rápida pesquisa no google deverá indicar alguns resultados relevantes que explicam essa migração em detalhes, incluindo principais pontes de atenção, como estes:

- http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2017/06/net-standard-voce-precisa-conhecer/
- https://xamarinhelp.com/upgrade-pcl-net-standard-class-library/
- http://www.stephanybatista.com/2017/08/03/net-standard-o-que-voce-precisa-saber-e-o-seu-beneficio/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/10/27/converting-pcl-portable-class-libraries-libraries-to-net-standard-class-libraries/

> Como fazer funcionar este plugin sendo que o Visual Studio não dá a opção para criar projetos PCL e somente .NET Standard

Se você já tem um projeto criado no formato PCL você deverá ser capaz de usá-lo normalmente. Caso contrário, como foi dito antes, é provavel que o plugin funcione normalmente em um projeto .Net Standard, apesar do alerta. Caso o comportamento seja diferente disso, o interessante seria avaliar específicamente os problemas em questão (certamente não seria uma mensagem de alerta).

> Como fazer para que este plugin se torne compatível com meu projeto.

Como disponível nas [informações do pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.BLE/), o projeto Plugin BLE 1.3.0 é open source. Para que se torne compatível é necessário alterar o código fonte [de acordo com a política de contribuição do projeto](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le) incluíndo um release para suporte ao novo padrão `.Net Standard`. Será necessário ter algum domínio sobre pacotes NuGet

Espero ter ajudado.